# Rails/Ruby - How to check if an attr_accessor field exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 3/4 model, if a field `field1` is declared with `attr_accessor`:

```
attr_accessor :field1
```

How to check late on if `field1` exists in the model?. `column_exists?` and `method_defined?` seem only working with model column and `field1` is not a model column.

Comment: what's the version of the Rails?

Comment: You can access to fied1 using `yourvariable.field1`
Once you do `variable = Model.new` , the column exist, if you want to test if it is empty you can run `variable.field1 === nil`

Comment: ruby_on_raIls 3.2 or above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`attr_accessor` defines two methods: `def field1` and `def field1=(val)`, so the best you can do is check for existence of these two functions.

If you have an object:

```
object.respond_to? :field1
object.respond_to? :field1=
```

If you don't, use:

```
Class.instance_methods.include? :field1
Class.instance_methods.include? :field1=
```

Comment: Does it give you false positives or false negatives?

Comment: `Class.instance_methods` returns both getter and setter.

Comment: respond_to? has to give you the right result, it's basic ruby. Something else is going on, your code is not what you think it is or what you've told us it is.  https://gist.github.com/jrochkind/4864c69a33ba605e72da

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor` will create getter and setter method in class

In Rails, the method `column_names` will return the array of column names. You can check if the column is present in it or not.

```
ModelClass.column_names.include?('column_name')
```

If you are not using Rails but just plain old Ruby and you want to check if getter setter are defined then you should use `respond_to?` method on the object.

Comment: `ModelClass.column_names` only returns the fields in the table and not the ones defined by `attr_accessor`.